# Googlecharts gem - where do I put the require 'gchart'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

On the following page it says how to use the googlecharts gem

http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/

It has a line that says

```
require 'gchart'
```

Where do I put this? In the gemfile or the controller?

EDIT:
In my view file I have:

```
<%
require 'gchart'
Gchart.line(:size => '200x300', 
        :title => "example title",
        :bg => 'efefef',
        :legend => ['first data set label', 'second data set label'],
        :data => [10, 30, 120, 45, 72]) 
%>
```

But the above does not display an image

EDIT 2:
The chart is now working, here is the code I used

```
<% require 'gchart' %>

<img src="<%=Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20])%>"/>
```

Comment: Have you installed correctly the googlecharts as is written here $ sudo gem install googlecharts ?

Comment: Yes when I run 'bundle install', it says 'Using googlecharts (1.6.7)'

Comment: Please, do not mix views with Ruby require statements.

Comment: I get no 'such file to load -- gchart' when I try your code (and I have added gem 'googlecharts' to my Gemfile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a require statement in your `Gemfile`. See [Bundler documentation](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html).

```
gem "googlecharts", :require => "gchart"
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to restart your server