# no such file to load -- google_chart using gem gchartrb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to use the [gem gchartrb](http://code.google.com/p/gchartrb/) to create some graphs/charts in my RoR application.

I have looked into several tutorial and all say the same thing, that I have to add

```
require 'google_chart'
```

But I am getting the message:

> no such file to load -- google_chart

I have the require inside my controller, I have confirmed that the gem is installed.
I am using Rails 3.

Also, I have tried adding `config.gem 'gchartrb', :lib => 'google_chart'` in my environment.rb as suggested [here](http://www.infoq.com/articles/bass-google-charts-gchartrb) but nothing changed

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I have also tried with the gem googlecharts, what I have in my Gemfile is:

```
gem "googlecharts", :require => "gchart"
```

but I get `no such file to load -- gchart` when I try to load the view.

Comment: Its seems that google charts gem does not work with rails 3, so I marked the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.gem` is for rails 2.3.X.
For rails 3, you will need to add the gem to your Gemfile and run `gem bundle`

You may also need to check that the google_charts gem actually supports Rails 3...
Given that the latest code update seems to have been in 2008 - that might not actually be likely. :(

You can try it anyway and see...

Comment: Hi Taryn, I have the gem in my Gemfile and ran bungle install, the gem is intalled. You are right, gchartrb might not be supported in Rails3, I am also trying with googlecharts, and have gem "googlecharts", :require => "gchart" in my gemfile as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703079/googlecharts-gem-where-do-i-put-the-require-gchart but I still have the same problem "no such file to load gchart"

Comment: silly question (just to rule it out), but before "bundle install" you did a "gem install gchart" yeah?

Comment: Its seems that google charts gem does not work with rails 3, so I marked the question as answered.

Comment: Ah - yeah, there are plenty of gems that haven't been updated to work with rails3 yet :(

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, it is required now or not. But it worked for me in Rails 3 as well. I am using Rails 3.0.10. I added below 2 lines and it worked for me.

1) gem 'gchartrb' in Gemfile
2) require 'google_chart' in config/boot.rb

Hope it helps!